# rake command not running from cron job but works otherwise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, rake

Operating System: Ubuntu installed on a docker and a normal ubuntu installed on my personal laptop.

I am running this cron job:

```
*/5 * * * * /bin/bash -l -c "cd /home/deploy/railsapp && rake spec >> cron.log 2>&1"
```

I have tried it with bundle exec rake spec, without /bin/bash, with whenever gem, with /usr/local/bin/rake spec, but still nothing is happening except these errors.

Errors in the log file on running the cron job:

```
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found


/bin/bash: rake: command not found


rake aborted!
Bundler::GemNotFound: Could not find rake-11.2.2 in any of the sources
/home/deploy/railsapp/config/boot.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/home/deploy/railsapp/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/deploy/railsapp/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
LoadError: cannot load such file -- bundler/setup
/home/deploy/railsapp/config/boot.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/home/deploy/railsapp/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/deploy/railsapp/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)


    bundler: failed to load command: rake (/usr/local/bin/rake)
        Bundler::GemNotFound: Could not find rake-11.2.2 in any of the sources
          /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:95:in `block in materialize'
          /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:88:in `map!'
          /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:88:in `materialize'
          /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:140:in `specs'
          /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:185:in `specs_for'
          /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:174:in `requested_specs'
          /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/environment.rb:19:in `requested_specs'
          /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:14:in `setup'
          /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler.rb:95:in `setup'
          /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/setup.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
          /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
          /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
```

On running `rake spec` manually from the command line its working fine, but from cron it is giving this error.
Any ideas ?

Comment: Are you running the cron with the same user? Looks like the user cron is running on doe not have access to the required gems.

Comment: Hi thanks for answer, its running as root, there is no user in OS.. it has only root user, running as a container inside docker

Comment: Maybe docker is cause of the problem? Try to add `docker` tag for question and write about it in question text.

Comment: It gives same error on my local machine, so docker has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am pretty sure that the issue is caused by not correctly set environment. Basically cron runs with the minimal environment so it is not aware about settings from for example `.bashrc` file (where you have `rvm` or `rbenv` initialization and `PATH` settings).

Source your environment file using `.` so rewrite the `cron` entry to something like:

```
*/5 * * * * /bin/bash -l -c ". /etc/environment && cd /home/deploy/railsapp && rake spec >> cron.log 2>&1"
```

Note that `/etc/environment` is just an example. You can source files like `.bashrc` instead.

Comment: I don't have rbenv or rvm paths in the .bashrc i have checked alll .bashrc

Comment: But you are using rbenv or rvm, right? If yes, you should have related code somewhere in environment files. It wouldn't work without it.

Comment: found it in /home/myuser/.bashrc ... its rbenv . But still same error : Bundler::GemNotFound: Could not find rake-11.2.2 in any of the sources, I have two rakes installed one is 10.something and one is 11.2.2, both are in same directory called gems.

Comment: so still PATH or GEM_PATH is not set properly

Comment: ok, which paths should I set? I am doing this now `*/5 * * * * /bin/bash -l -c ". /path/to/myCustomScript.sh && cd /home/deploy/railsapp && rake spec >> cron.log 2>&1"`  in myCustomScript.sh I have set this path : `export GEM_PATH=/usr/local/bundle/gems` , i am still getting the same error :(

Comment: I also did source /path/to/.bashrc , still the same error, i am using rbenv

Comment: It all depends on your environment. Afaik it should be enough to run rvm initialization but i may be wrong. You can run bundle check in cron, redirect output and see it from file.

Comment: thanks a lot for help, issue is resolved, path was the problem, you were right

Answer (score 3):

I use `whenever` gem to manage crontab.

Adding

```
ENV.each { |k, v| env(k, v) }
```

to the `config/schedule.rb` file solved this issue for me.

**Reference:** https://github.com/javan/whenever/issues/656#issuecomment-239111064

Answer (score 0):

Use [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) gem - this is adapter for cron, with support of rake tasks and other ruby/rails things.