# bundle: command not found when run script

Tags: linux, redmine

I want to create a script to send remind expire issue in redmine. When I run this script by manual, it's ok. But when I create a crontab to run it, it did not run and show the error log: "bundle: command not found".
My script:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /opt/redmine-5.0.2
bundle exec rake redmine:send_reminders days=1 RAILS_ENV="production"
```

I try to add full path of bundle to script

````
#!/bin/bash
cd /opt/redmine-5.0.2
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/bin/bundle exec rake redmine:send_reminders days=1 RAILS_ENV="production"```

It shown that 

bundler: failed to load command: rake (/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/bin/rake)
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/spec_set.rb:87:in `block in materialize': Could not find rake-13.0.6 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/spec_set.rb:81:in `map!'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/spec_set.rb:81:in `materialize'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/definition.rb:175:in `specs'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/definition.rb:245:in `specs_for'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/definition.rb:227:in `requested_specs'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/runtime.rb:91:in `block in definition_method'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/runtime.rb:20:in `setup'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler.rb:149:in `setup'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/setup.rb:20:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/ui/shell.rb:136:in `with_level'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/ui/shell.rb:88:in `silence'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/setup.rb:20:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/cli/exec.rb:61:in `require_relative'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/cli/exec.rb:61:in `kernel_load'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/cli/exec.rb:28:in `run'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/cli.rb:497:in `exec'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/cli.rb:30:in `dispatch'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:485:in `start'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/cli.rb:24:in `start'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.3/libexec/bundle:49:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:130:in `with_friendly_errors'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.3/libexec/bundle:37:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'

Thanks for your support.
````

Comment: Tell me if https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39037735/rake-command-not-running-from-cron-job-but-works-otherwise is a good solution. (a quick search on SO web site)...

Comment: Thanks Gilles Quénot, I try to add source "/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm" into my script, and it's oke now, I also dont need to add PATH.